# The entity type <User> is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, ado.net, crud

I keep getting this exception when I try to registarte a user to my database.
I have tryed several solutions but the problem is still persist. Including these: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/20688922/the-entity-type--type--is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

I get the exception when I send the form, and the exception happens when this function tries to execute:

I have two db context:

```
namespace CRUDProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class DeskDatabaseUsers : DbContext
    {
        public DeskDatabaseUsers(): base("name=DeskDatabaseUsers")
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        }
        public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CRUDProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using CRUDProject.Extensions;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class DeskDatabaseEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DeskDatabaseEntities():base("name=DeskDatabaseEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Table>().ToTable("Table");
        }
        
        public virtual DbSet<Table> Table { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my code bellow:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CRUDProject.Extensions;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CRUDProject.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Web.Util;



namespace CRUDProject.Models
{
    public class TableController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            
            using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
            {
                
                return View(dbModel.Table.ToList());
            }
            
        }

        [HttpGet]
        //GET: Table/Registration
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //GET: Table/Login
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // GET: Table/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return View(dbModel.Table.Where(x=>x.Id==id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
            
        }

        // GET: Table/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // POST: Table/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Table table)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    dbModel.Table.Add(table);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                    this.AddNotification("Sikeres asztalfoglalás!", NotificationType.SUCCESS);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                this.AddNotification("Sikertelen asztalfoglalás!", NotificationType.ERROR);
            }
            return View();
        }
        // GET: Table/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return View(dbModel.Table.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        // POST: Table/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Table table)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    
                    dbModel.Entry(table).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                    this.AddNotification("Sikeres változtatás", NotificationType.SUCCESS);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Table/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return View(dbModel.Table.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
        #region NonActionSegment
        [NonAction]
        public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string emailID, string activationCode)
        {
            var verifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;
            var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

            var fromEmail = new MailAddress("finywow@gmail.com", "Dotnet Awesome");
            var toEmail = new MailAddress(emailID);
            var fromEmailPassword = "********"; // Replace with actual password
            string subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

            string body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your Dotnet Awesome account is" +
                " successfully created. Please click on the below link to verify your account" +
                " <br/><br/><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> ";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
            };

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            })
                smtp.Send(message);
        }
        [NonAction]
        public bool IsEmailExist(string emailID)
        {
            using (DeskDatabaseUsers dc = new DeskDatabaseUsers())
            {
                var v = dc.User.Where(a => a.EmailID == emailID).FirstOrDefault();
                return v != null;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified,ActivationCode")] User user)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            string message = "";
            //
            // Model Validation 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                #region //Email is already Exist 
                var isExist = IsEmailExist(user.EmailID);
                if (isExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email already exist");
                    return View(user);
                }
                #endregion

                #region Generate Activation Code 
                user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                #endregion

                #region  Password Hashing 
                user.Password = Crypto.Hash(user.Password);
                user.ConfirmPassword = Crypto.Hash(user.ConfirmPassword); //
                #endregion
                user.IsEmailVerified = false;

                #region Save to Database
                using (DeskDatabaseUsers dc = new DeskDatabaseUsers())
                {
                    dc.User.Add(user);
                    dc.SaveChanges();

                    //Send Email to User
                    SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.EmailID, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
                    message = "Registration successfully done. Account activation link " +
                        " has been sent to your email id:" + user.EmailID;
                    Status = true;
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(user);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult VerifyAccount(string id)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            using (DeskDatabaseUsers dbmod=new DeskDatabaseUsers())
            {
                dbmod.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                var v = dbmod.User.Where(a => a.ActivationCode == new Guid(id)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v!=null)
                {
                    v.IsEmailVerified = true;
                    dbmod.SaveChanges();
                    Status = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Request";
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View();
        }
        // POST: Table/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)// NOT SURE IF THIS WORKS PROPERLY
        {
            try
            {
                using (DeskDatabaseEntities dbModel = new DeskDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    Table table = dbModel.Table.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    this.AddNotification("Sikeres törlés", NotificationType.SUCCESS);
                    dbModel.Table.Remove(table);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                this.AddNotification("Az elem már törlésre került", NotificationType.ERROR);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The function where the exception appears:
`
[NonAction]
        public bool IsEmailExist(string emailID)
        {
            using (DeskDatabaseUsers dc = new DeskDatabaseUsers())
            {
                var v = dc.User.Where(a => a.EmailID == emailID).FirstOrDefault();
                return v != null;
            }
        }`

Comment: Add the DbSet<User> to the DeskDatabaseEntities context

Comment: Sadly the Exception still appears